# Getting the first instance of a zero value in a table of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many horses and their values which reduce over time.  I would like to be able to fetch only the rows where the value of each horse becomes 0 for the first time.  There are multiple rows for each horse where the values are 0 but I want the earliest of them.  My table looks like this and I need to return the rowID and the others if possible (8 and 20 in this example).  I tried using the rank over partition but could not get that to work for me and I would paste the example but frankly it was rubbish.  Thank you in advance.

| rowID | horseID | valueYear | valueMonth | value | I need these rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1990 | 7 | 1000 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1991 | 1 | 900 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 1992 | 2 | 800 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 1993 | 4 | 700 |  |
| 5 | 1 | 1993 | 7 | 690 |  |
| 6 | 1 | 1995 | 3 | 500 |  |
| 7 | 1 | 1995 | 7 | 470 |  |
| 8 | 1 | 1997 | 8 | 0 | <---- |
| 9 | 1 | 1998 | 2 | 0 |  |
| 10 | 1 | 1999 | 3 | 0 |  |
| 11 | 1 | 2000 | 9 | 0 |  |
| 12 | 2 | 1990 | 3 | 900 |  |
| 13 | 2 | 1991 | 1 | 750 |  |
| 14 | 2 | 1992 | 7 | 700 |  |
| 15 | 2 | 1993 | 3 | 600 |  |
| 16 | 2 | 1993 | 4 | 590 |  |
| 17 | 2 | 1995 | 3 | 300 |  |
| 18 | 2 | 1995 | 9 | 170 |  |
| 19 | 2 | 1997 | 5 | 50 |  |
| 20 | 2 | 1998 | 6 | 0 | <---- |
| 21 | 2 | 1999 | 4 | 0 |  |
| 22 | 2 | 2000 | 2 | 0 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is WITH TIES in concert with `row_number()`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Where value = 0
 Order By row_number() over (partition by horseID order by rowID ) -- could be valueYear as well
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much John.  I have never experienced the WITH TIES before.  Very interesting.  And I applied it to my data and have the perfect results.  Thank you so much!!